# How do I make a "definition" template as shown?

Tags: diagrams, templates

Recently I started taking notes in LaTeX and wanted to know how I could make a reproducible "definition" template as shown below.

As shown in the images the sizes of the orange line vary depending on the amount of text. What would be the best reproducible method to do this?

[image: small definition size]

[image: large definition size]

Comment: Probably something with [tcolorbox](https://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox?lang=en).

Comment: Questions such as "What would be *the best* reproducible method" [emphasis added] are both virtually unanswerable and inherently subjective, since you haven't provided even a hint of a criterion you, or anybody else, might use to determine which method might be optimal. Are you willing to accept a *working*, reproducible method?

Comment: @Mico The criterion are the images provided. This isnt an abstract philosophical question, calm down.

Comment: @mickep thank you exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Jackwannsee - You specifically asked for the "best reproducible method"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{myframe}{
enhanced,
sharp corners=all,
colback=white,
colframe=orange,
toprule=0pt,
bottomrule=0pt,
leftrule=1.5pt,
rightrule=0pt,
overlay={\draw[orange,line width=1.5pt] (frame.south west) -- ++(1cm,0pt);}
}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{myframe}
\begin{definition}
Definition
\end{definition}
\begin{enumerate}
\item a
\item b
\item c
\end{enumerate}
\end{myframe}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you so much!